# Regular expression to find a string included between two bars and containing certain words

Tags: php, regex

I always forget regex right after learning it. I want to extract the isbn number from a string.

String: `English | ISBN: 1285463234 | 2014 | 499 pages | PDF | 28 MB`

Target to extract: `1285463234`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex to extract the ISBN number,

```
ISBN:\s*\K\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2eD7/3)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = 'English | ISBN: 1285463234 | 2014 | 499 pages | PDF | 28 MB';
$regex = '~ISBN:\s*\K\d+~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> 1285463234
```

**Explanation:**

- `ISBN:` Matches the string `ISBN:`
- `\s*` Matches zero or more spaces.
- `\K` Discards previously matched characters.(ie, `ISBN:`)
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findall` with this regex:

```
/(?<=ISBN: )\d+/
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2eD7/5)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=` Opens a positive lookahead group, asserts that this matches after:
- `ISBN:` Matches the string **"ISBN: "**
- `)` Closes the lookahead group.
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with regex, there are also other libraries which can do it with your straight forward example, for example the [`sscanf` function in the PHP string library](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
$subject = 'English | ISBN: 1285463234 | 2014 | 499 pages | PDF | 28 MB';
$result  = sscanf($subject, 'English | ISBN: %d | ', $isbn);
```

If there is a match (`$result` is 1), the `$isbn` variable will contain the ISBN number as *integer*:

```
int(1285463234)
```

ISBN numbers never start with 0, so this should not pose any problem. If you need is as string, use `%s` instead of `%d`:

```
$result  = sscanf($subject, 'English | ISBN: %s | ', $isbn);
```

The result is then a string:

```
string(10) "1285463234"
```

Scanf patterns are way easier to deal with less complex string parsing than PCRE regular expressions (which have more power but are also more complex). Also the assignment to a specific variable is easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

An exact representation (and also a patchwork of the other answers ^^) would be this:

```
(?<=\| ISBN: )(\S+)(?= \|)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Mv0-6FTsB0IyINUE)